# Change name of uploaded image to a specific name

Tags: php

I have got an upload form for uploading images, I want to change the name of the image to a specific name.

This is my code:

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
    echo '{"status":"success"}';
    exit;
}
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

Comment: SO what is the error you are receiving or the problem you are facing?

Comment: All you are doing it giving it the same name as it had before.  PHP isn't doing that, but you are.  Look at the second argument of the `move_uploaded_file` function

Answer (score 0):

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/your_own_name_here.'$extension)){
    echo '{"status":"success"}';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: it dosent work, is it possible i gv u a link to downlod the full source code, so u can see the full implementation

Comment: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/#comment-85865,                                                                download from there and see wat am saying, if eventually u make d correct changes to what i want, u can leave it and post it, would really appreciate

Comment: $extention = expload('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$your_own_name = 'MyImage'.$extention;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$your_own_name)){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }

Comment: just copy and paste the above code instead of if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
    echo '{"status":"success"}';
    exit;
}

Comment: did u test it before posting its honestly not working, confused

Answer (score 0):

you should change **$_FILES['upl']['name']** in following code

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
```

for example :

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/nameOfTheFile.jpg')){
```

Comment: it dosent work, is it possible i gv u a link to downlod the full source code, so u can see the full implementation

Answer (score 0):

you can add your custom file name in calling function `move_uploaded_file`.
like,

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.'yourcustomname'.$extension )){
```

If you want to add unique name then you can use like,

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.time().$extension )){
```

Comment: it dosent work, is it possible i gv u a link to downlod the full source code, so u can see the full implementation

Answer (score 0):

Changed to reflect your question, will produce a random number based on the current time and append the extension from the originally uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename);
```

Comment: a few details on what would be the filename at the end would be great